# Why is this an ambiguous call to Constructor (const path& -vs- const vector<path>&)?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, ambiguous

I have a class, `DataHandler`, with two constructors:

```cpp
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

class DataHandler {
public:
  explicit DataHandler(const fs::path & dataPath);
  DataHandler(const std::vector<fs::path> &dataPaths);
  ...
}
```

In `int main()`, I instantiate a `DataHandler`, attempting to initialize using the 2nd CTOR using a initializer list:

```cpp
const fs::path basePath = "../data";
std::vector<fs::path> dataPaths;
fs::path trainCsv = basePath / "train.csv";
fs::path testCsv = basePath / "test.csv";
dataPaths.push_back(trainCsv);
dataPaths.push_back(testCsv);

//DataHandler dh(dataPaths);
DataHandler dh({trainCsv, testCsv});
```

Instead of creating a `vector` and calling CTOR#2, the compiler says that this is an ambiguous call. I've looked at [the various `filesystem::path` constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path), and can't figure out which one would conflict with CTOR#2.

Compiler errors:

```
.../src/main.cpp:36:17: error: call to constructor of 'DataHandler' is ambiguous
    DataHandler dh({trainCsv, testCsv});
                ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.../include/DataHandler.hpp:49:14: note: candidate constructor
    explicit DataHandler(const fs::path & dataPath);
             ^
.../include/DataHandler.hpp:50:5: note: candidate constructor
    DataHandler(const std::vector<fs::path> &dataPaths);
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Can someone please describe what the compiler is seeing that I am not?

### Rewritten to reproduce with minimal code

I am getting same errors with the following code:

```cpp
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

class DataHandler {
public:
    explicit DataHandler(const fs::path & dataPath) {
        cout << "In path CTOR" << endl;
    };
    DataHandler(const std::vector<fs::path> &dataPaths) {
        cout << "In vector CTOR" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const fs::path basePath = "../data";
    std::vector<fs::path> dataPaths;
    fs::path trainCsv = basePath / "train.csv";
    fs::path testCsv = basePath / "test.csv";
    dataPaths.push_back(trainCsv);
    dataPaths.push_back(testCsv);

    //DataHandler dh(dataPaths);
    DataHandler dh({trainCsv, testCsv});
}
```

### Building an `fs::path` with init_list of two items:

`fs::path p({"/path1", "path2"});` yields following candidates:

1. `_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY path(path&& __p) noexcept : __pn_(_VSTD::move(__p.__pn_)) {}`
2. `_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY path(const path& __p) : __pn_(__p.__pn_) {}`
3. `_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY path(string_type&& __s, format = format::auto_format) noexcept : __pn_(_VSTD::move(__s)) {}`

Comment: Doesn't the compiler tell you this, directly? This error message is typically followed by a list of possible overloads that were considered, and determined to be ambiguous. What are the possible overloads that are listed in the rest of the error message?

Comment: Reproduced it with MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/GE5EYfhE8 (and nothing else)

Comment: [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path) has constructor (#6) taking 2 `InputIt` which doesn't seems restricted, so would be a "viable" candidate...

Comment: Write with double-braces to fix the issue. Like `{{transCsv, testCsv}}`.

Comment: Not directly related, but why isn't  your second constructor declared explicit as well?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy in event I pass vector of string instead of path.

Comment: The `explicit` keyword is used to prevent accidental calls to the constructor, as an inadvertent construction of a DataHandler from a string (for example) when calling functions.  This is why constructors with a single parameter are declared explicit, unless the implicit call to the constructor (conversion) is actually desired.  Shouldn't the same protection apply to vectors?  Just something you should consider.